# Barra de rolagem do navbar não aparece em outra largura

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Usei o código abaixo para alterar quando é exibido o botão de menu para mobile e funcionou, porém a barra de rolagem não aparece neste tamanho. O que eu posso fazer para exibir a barra de rolagem? Se precisar eu coloco imagens.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

**ATUALIZADO:**

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/c80tn7qh/1/

**Imagens:**

[image: Sem a barra de rolagem]

[image: Com a barra de rolagem]

Comment: Não sei como está seu `navbar`, mas tenta colocar no `.navbar-header`um `overflow: auto` ou `overflow: visible`.

Comment: Fiz o teste, não deu certo. Vou colocar o código do navbar e o os prints. Valeu!

Comment: Você consegue montar um Fiddle ?

Comment: Sim. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c80tn7qh/1/

Comment: coloca o primeiro elemento pai dos itens listados como absolute, e o pai dele você da o overflow

Comment: Acho que ainda não entendi o que você precisa.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo aumenta a largadura da janela, os itens pulam para fora e não exibe o scrollbar.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa parece que funcionou, mas quando o menu termina de carregar ele some e exibe todos os itens. Coloquei `overflow-y: scroll` na `DIV` e `position: absolute` no `UL`.

Comment: Veja se é isso o que você precisa ? https://jsfiddle.net/c80tn7qh/3/

Comment: @Zooboomafoo isso! Só falta exibir alguns itens apenas e exibir a barra para visualizar os outros

Comment: Assim ? https://jsfiddle.net/c80tn7qh/4/

Comment: Deu certo minha sugestão ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo isso, deu sim! Fui fazer um teste e vi que o comportamento normal do navbar é empurrar o conteúdo para baixo (fica melhor), fiz alguma coisa que mudou isso, por isso pensei em usar scrollbar. De qualquer forma, resolveu o problema, era só acrescentar `.navbar-header {float: none;}`. Obrigado.

Comment: Vou postar com o resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar{
    overflow: auto;
  }
      
        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none!important;
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
            display: block!important;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            margin: 7.5px -15px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 10px" href="index.php"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PRODUTOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTE</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CONTEÚDOS</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">DA PESQUISA À INOVAÇÃO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">IMPRENSA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EXCLUSIVO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente para "forçar" a barra de rolagem é usado [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) no alvo. Exemplo:

```
body {
  overflow-x: scroll; // somente para horizontal
  overflow-y: scroll; // somente para vertical
  overflow: scroll; // horizontal e vertical
}
```

Pode ser aplicado a elementos específicos também, como `div` ou estilos.

**Sintaxe:**

> overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;

Comment: A barra do menu que não aparece, não especifiquei direito. Fiz um teste colocando no .navbar-nav e exibiu só a barra sem o "botão" para arrastar, mas os itens ficam pra fora. Vou colocar os prints para ficar melhor. Valeu!